# C++ Realsense openCV facedetection - access

Tags: c++, opencv, realsense

I am new to Realsense & C++. I know this question might be easy on.
However, I cannot solve this even I searched half of day.

I am trying to use Realsense with OpenCV face detection(Haarcascade).
But when I use 'face_cascade,detectMultiScale', the project gets access violation error. 
(just like the picture underneath)

[image]

and my codes are this :

```html
// License: Apache 2.0.See LICENSE file in root directory.
// Copyright(c) 2017 Intel Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

#include <rs.hpp> // Include RealSense Cross Platform API
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>   // Include OpenCV API
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//String face_cascade_name;
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
string window_name = "Face detection";

void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame)
{
 std::vector<Rect> faces;
 Mat frame_gray;
 
 cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
 equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);
 if (frame.empty()) {
  printf("error, no data");
 }
 else {
  printf("no problem");
 }
 //face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));
 face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces , 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(500, 500));

 for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
 {
  Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width / 2, faces[i].y + faces[i].height / 2);
  ellipse(frame, center, Size(faces[i].width / 2, faces[i].height / 2),
   0, 0, 360, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);
 }
 
 imshow(window_name, frame);
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) try
{
 // Declare depth colorizer for pretty visualization of depth data
 rs2::colorizer color_map;

 // Declare RealSense pipeline, encapsulating the actual device and sensors
 rs2::pipeline pipe;
 
 face_cascade.load("C:\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
 //if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name)) { printf("--(!)Error loading face cascade\n"); };
 

 // Start streaming with default recommended configuration
 pipe.start();

 const auto window_name = "Display Image";
 namedWindow(window_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

 while (waitKey(1) < 0 && cvGetWindowHandle(window_name))
 {
  rs2::frameset data = pipe.wait_for_frames(); // Wait for next set of frames from the camera
  //rs2::frame depth = color_map(data.get_depth_frame());
  rs2::frame color = data.get_color_frame();

  // Query frame size (width and height)
  //const int w = depth.as<rs2::video_frame>().get_width();
  //const int h = depth.as<rs2::video_frame>().get_height();

  const int color_w = color.as<rs2::video_frame>().get_width();
  const int color_h = color.as<rs2::video_frame>().get_height();

  // Create OpenCV matrix of size (w,h) from the colorized depth data
  //Mat image(Size(w, h), CV_8UC3, (void*)depth.get_data(), Mat::AUTO_STEP);
  Mat image(Size(color_w, color_h), CV_8UC3, (void*)color.get_data(), Mat::AUTO_STEP);

  // Update the window with new data
  //imshow(window_name, image);

  detectAndDisplay(image);
 }

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
catch (const rs2::error & e)
{
 std::cerr << "RealSense error calling " << e.get_failed_function() << "(" << e.get_failed_args() << "):\n    " << e.what() << std::endl;
 return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
 std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
 return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

enter code here